# Why do some C projects like nginx and LuaJIT prefix all their code files, functions and data types with the project's name?

Tags: c, coding-style

Looking at nginx's code I see that pretty much everything is prefixed with `ngx_`.

Files:

```
ngx_list.c
ngx_list.h
ngx_log.c
ngx_log.h
```

Code:

```
ngx_log_t *ngx_log_init(u_char *prefix);
void ngx_cdecl ngx_log_abort(ngx_err_t err, const char *fmt, ...);
void ngx_cdecl ngx_log_stderr(ngx_err_t err, const char *fmt, ...);
```

LuaJIT is pretty much the same thing but with `lj_`.

Files:

```
lj_alloc.c
lj_alloc.h
lj_api.c
lj_arch.h
```

Code:

```
LJ_ASMF void LJ_FASTCALL lj_vm_ffi_call(CCallState *cc);
LJ_FUNC CTypeID lj_ccall_ctid_vararg(CTState *cts, cTValue *o);
LJ_FUNC int lj_ccall_func(lua_State *L, GCcdata *cd);
```

Other project's do the same thing, these are just two that come to mind. Why do they do this? If it was the project's public API I would get it as it will be exposed to third party code. But the code I copied is part of the (private) implementation so why namespace it?

Comment: Linking is the problem, in general out of the hands of the library author.  The lack of support for namespaces in the C language is a very significant obstacle.  So you see this code creating their own with a prefix.  Makes less sense for naming files, but naming collisions between object files (library vs client program) is a very ugly problem as well.  The client's log.o overwriting the library's log.o file produces dastardly hard to diagnose link errors.

Comment: @HansPassant As long as the library is built as a standard `.a`, `.so`, `.lib`, or `.dll` file, there should be no problem with individual object file name collisions.

Comment: Sure, these problems are not particularly hard to avoid.  If you know about them.  It is the mishaps experienced by newbie programmers that put a major drain on the library's support channels.

Comment: For the file names, it's because some editors don't display the full path, only the file name on tabs (or buffers list), so it's easier to look up and switch to the right file if they have the project prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there's no hard-and-fast reason.  I suspect it's just something that people (some people) feel more comfortable with.  I wouldn't do it myself, but I guess I can see the appeal.

For example, I have a multiprecision arithmetic library I wrote for fun one day.  It has functions like `mp_add()`, `mt_sub()`, etc.  And the source for these functions lives in files `add.c` and `sub.c`.

Now, since all the source code for this library lives in a subdirectory named `mp`, I have never been tempted to give the files names like `mp_add.c` or `mp_sub.c`.  That would just be redundant: the names are already in a very real sense `mp/add.c`, `mp/sub.c`, etc.

But I have to admit that it does feel a teensy bit weird going to a file named `add.c` to check on my *multiprecision* addition code.  It's not integer addition code, or fixed-point or rational-number addition code, or general-purpose addition code.  It's very specifically multiprecision addition code, and the functions defined within do all have that `mp_` prefix.  So shouldn't the filename have that prefix, also?

As I said, no, in the end I wouldn't (I didn't) give it that prefix.  But as I also said, I guess I can see the appeal.

---

Addendum: Above I answered about filenames, but you also asked about internal -- "private" -- function names.  And those are different; those definitely need a prefix, at least in C.

The issue is that *C does not really have any namespace mechanisms*.  So you almost always have to fake it with project-specific prefixes on all global symbols.

Consider the function `ngx_log_abort()`.  It's private to nginx; client code wouldn't be calling it.  But it's a global function, so if it were just named `log_abort`, there would be a pretty high chance of a collision with a completely different function in the the client code (or in some other library code) also named `log_abort`.

You may ask, then why is `ngx_log_abort` a global function?  And of course the answer is that any of the functions making up the nginx library might need to call it, so it pretty much has to be global.

You may ask, then why isn't `ngx_log_abort` a file-scope `static` function?  And the answer there is, that would work *if* all the source code for the entire nginx library were confined to a single C source file `nginx.c`.  But the authors probably didn't want to confine themselves that way.

If you want to write a well-encapsulated library in C, you have two choices for your "private" functions:

1. Make them file-scope `static`, and limit yourself to using a single source file for most or all of your library.
2. Make them truly global, but with uniqueifying prefixes.  Also don't put declarations for them in public header files.  (That way clients can't call them without cheating.)

In other languages you have other mechanisms for hiding private symbols, but not in C.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: There is another option of making the library, performing a partial link and strip the"private" symbols.